# avoid process with before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building the user permissions and I am trying to use "before_action" evaluating a conditional, if it returns true I want the "create" action not to be executed but if it returns true that records can be created

that would be my before_action

```
before_action :permiso_create, only: [:create]

def create
  @producto = Producto.new(producto_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @producto.save
      format.html { redirect_to @producto, notice: 'Producto was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @producto }
      format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'El producto se ha creado de forma exitosa.'} #ajax
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @producto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js {flash.now[:alert] = 'Error al crear el producto.'} #ajax

    end
  end
end
```

I want if the conditional returns true, do not create a record or do not execute the action create, only that it shows a flash alert with the message of "permission denied"

```
def permiso_create
  @puede_crear = current_usuario.profiles.find_by_Descripcion("products").Altas
  if @puede_crear != true


  end
end
```

I tried with unprocessable_entity but it does not show me the message js, like this:

```
def permiso_create
  @puede_crear = current_usuario.profiles.find_by_Descripcion("products").Altas
  if @puede_crear != true
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {flash.now[:alert] = 'you don't have permission.'} #ajax
      end
     head :unprocessable_entity

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a gem for this called [ActionControl](https://github.com/tobiasfeistmantl/action_control) which gives you the opportunity to authenticate and authorize users in the controller directly.

If the user is not authorized it raises an exception and the action does not get executed. You then catch this exception and respond to the user with a 401 or 403 status.

If you don't want to use the gem you can also do this by yourself by raising an exception in the `permiso_create` method and catch this one.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `return` after your validation

```
def permiso_create
  @puede_crear = current_usuario.profiles.find_by_Descripcion("products").Altas
  if @puede_crear != true
    # you can return a flash message before stop the flow here
    @foo = nil
    return

  end
end
```

This will stop the flow

EDIT: adding a condition

```
before_action :permiso_create, only: [:create]
def create
  if @foo.nil?
    return
  end
  #continue with your code
end
```

Comment: yes it stop the flow but within the method "permiso_create", and do not stop the method create

Comment: @luis31 you can return a variable and add a condition when you use before_action I edited my answer

Comment: Also, you can find more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks)

Comment: that way it does not continue executing the conditional of the "permiso_create" method. and the problem is that using only the return only stops the flow of the "permiso_create" method and executes the create method

Comment: @luis31 I see your point, then you can validate the variable existence inside your created method, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should still probably format the response, even if your condition is not met. This should do:

```
def permiso_create
  @puede_crear = current_usuario.profiles.find_by_Descripcion("products").Altas
  unless @puede_crear
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {flash.now[:alert] = "you don't have permission.", status: :unprocessable_entity} 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it works, it stops the cycle but the problem is that I tried to send a message by js before and it does not show it on the screen, I updated the post with the way I send the message with the unprocessable_entity

Comment: I get this error: SyntaxError (/home/luis/sites/adcv2/app/controllers/productos_controller.rb:198: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
...on't have permission.", status: :unprocessable_entity}
...                               ^):
  app/controllers/productos_controller.rb:198: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL